# Countdown in Repeater asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a repeater, which read last date,
but I want to this last date have like countdown,
I found some code on internet but it does not work

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="TimedPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateTimer" EventName="Tick" />
                                        </Triggers>
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <%# GetTimeLeft((DateTime)Eval("RequestedDate")).ToString() %>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                      <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="UpdateTimer" Interval="1000" />
```

Thanks to this code I can write how much last date, but it does not work like countdown for example like [this](http://keith-wood.name/countdownBasics.html)

Comment: where is the repeater? And is this the code on the internet which you say doesn't work for you?

Comment: Repeater located in aspx page does it matter. And internet code you apogolozie i write wrong not code just update panel code behind doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

Let me break in 2 what I did to solve the issue:

First I build a server side sample code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("MyDate", typeof(DateTime));
        table.Rows.Add(new object[]{DateTime.Now.AddDays(+180)});
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] { DateTime.Now.AddDays(50)});
        ;
        myRepeater.DataSource = table;
        myRepeater.DataBind();
    }
```

And this is the HTML Version of the sample:

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="myRepeater">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div>
                        <div class="dt1" style="display:none;overflow:hidden"><%# ((DateTime)Eval("MyDate")).Year %>,<%# ((DateTime)Eval("MyDate")).Month-1 %>, <%# ((DateTime)Eval("MyDate")).Day %></div> 
                        <div class='dt2'></div>                 
                    </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </form>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).on('ready', function () {     
             $('.dt1').each(function (index, el) {
                 var value = $(this).text().split(',');               
                 var newYear = new Date(value[0], value[1], value[2]);                                
                 $(this).siblings('.dt2').countdown({ until: newYear });
             });             
         });
         </script>
```

To be totally honest I do not feel proud of :

```
                 <div class="dt1" style="display:none;overflow:hidden"><%# ((DateTime)Eval("MyDate")).Year %>,<%# ((DateTime)Eval("MyDate")).Month-1 %>, <%# ((DateTime)Eval("MyDate")).Day %></div>
```

and this:

```
var value = $(this).text().split(',');               
var newYear = new Date(value[0], value[1], value[2]);
```

It would been better to JSON Serialize the date and then work with the serialized version but I didn't want to over complicate this sample including a reference to a JSON Serializer and having to explain it as well.